# Trouble with Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I need to integrate the datepicker but its not working properly.

This is my HTML

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
         datepicker-popup="mediumDate" 
         is-open="shipment.valuationDatePickerIsOpen" 
        ng-click="shipment.valuationDatePickerOpen()" 
        ng-model="shipment.valuationDate" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
        ng-click="shipment.valuationDatePickerOpen($event)">
         <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
     </button>
</span>
</p>

</div>
```

And this is my controller

```
var vm = this;
    // $scope.Eship;

      vm.valuationDate = new Date();
  vm.valuationDatePickerIsOpen = false;
  vm.opens = [];

  $scope.$watch(function () {
       return vm.valuationDatePickerIsOpen;
   },function(value){
      vm.opens.push("valuationDatePickerIsOpen: " + value + " at: " + new Date());
   });

  vm.valuationDatePickerOpen = function ($event) {

      if ($event) {
          $event.preventDefault();
          $event.stopPropagation(); 
      }
      this.valuationDatePickerIsOpen = true;
  };
```

I already import the ui-bootstrap directive.
I dont know whats missing or whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the simplest example given in the documentation & then after customize or manipulate the Model value of that date input field,

```
<p class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" 
   datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
  </span>
</p>
```

Here's link for the plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/PbuiCq5f3NVaWx6OAW8D?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have the issue because you're using `datepicker-popup` instead of `uib-datepicker-popup` directive.
Just make sure you're using right versions of Angular and [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), then take a look on the Docs of that module.

I fixed your example, please find the code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/cMj8IXD7KYTUgi7hY0W7?p=preview

I hope it helps.

Comment: i did it like that, it works. but it doesnt update in data base. what im i doing wrong?

Comment: I thought your issue was with date picker integration. Perhaps you'll need to post another question for your data base/service integration.